# Create a <br /> when you press Enter

Tags: php, javascript, html, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have made a textarea form where you can change your description and like in my previus question I asked if there was any way of having banned tags. But now is there any way of when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> that a `<br />` will be set in the textarea so that the user doesn't have to type in `<br />` every time they want a line break?

I thought of something like if it can find places where there's nothing, but would this work? I'm not familiar with onpress events... Or if it checks the input after the user has pressed submit and then it checks for line breaks.

I have seen this on YouTube , this site and a lot of other sites too.

Comment: Are you wanting the textarea to automatically add a visible string "<br />" when the user presses enter or are you wanting the textarea to not display it but to include it on the back-end assuming the value is submitted to a database?

Comment: If you are also allowing some HTML, and that includes some block elements (like `P`) you might end up with double line breaks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PHP, you can use the [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to replace any newlines with `<br />` tags.

Comment: You're welcome. I actually hesitated with answering because I wasn't sure if you were looking for a frontend or backend implementation, since your tags listed both PHP and JavaScript. I'm a PHP guy, so I went with what I knew. ;) Glad to help.

Comment: I'm new here on this site so could you tell me how to do that, please? I can't find the button anywhere!

Comment: There's a checkmark below the vote area on my answer. If you click it, it'll mark the answer as accepted. It's optional, but appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#txt').keyup(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                var curr = getCaret(this);
                var val = $(this).val();
                var end = val.length;

                $(this).val( val.substr(0, curr) + '<br>' + val.substr(curr, end));
            }

        })
    });

    function getCaret(el) { 
        if (el.selectionStart) { 
            return el.selectionStart; 
        }
        else if (document.selection) { 
            el.focus(); 

            var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
            if (r == null) { 
                return 0; 
            } 

            var re = el.createTextRange(), 
            rc = re.duplicate(); 
            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

            return rc.text.length; 
        }  
        return 0; 
    }

</script>
<div id="content">
    <textarea id="txt" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as :

```
function createBr(e) {


   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      document.createElement("BR");
       //do what you want with it
   }
}
```

Hope it helps